# uiwebview disable scrolling

Tags: ios, uiwebview, offline

I was wondering if someone could assist me in how to **disable** the scrolling function on UIWebView on Xcode.

I'll try explain my issue as best as possible.

I'm trying to disable the scrolling function so that the user cannot scroll up or down on the webview. Is there a way to somehow block the scrolling function?

If you need more information please let me know.

Many thanks.

Comment: hope this helps you:                                    webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;

Comment: Hi Sujania, where would I place this?

Comment: Add this line below the allocation of webview if  webView created programatically, else in viewDidLoad

Comment: Thanks I will try this now, If i have issue I will comment :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To disable scroll view in UIWebview,Wirte this inside ur viewDidLoad

```
webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

also

```
webview.scalesPageToFit = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

write this inside ur viewDidLoad if you not use CollectionView / TableView

```
webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
webView.scrollView.bounces = false
```

if you use CollectionView / TableView

you can write on awakeFromNib